# Can't Create a Permanent Alias In Fish Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

I'm trying to create a permanent alias. I've created one long ago, but I don't remember if I did anything differently than what I'm doing now. Be as it may, it isn't working!

I start by opening the terminal and type

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then I scroll to the end (just in case, I don't know) and type

```
alias pd="pwd"
```

(this is not the alias I'm actually creating).

When I close and save the bashrc file I type `pd` and the command isn't recognized. Plus, when I type the alias command to see my aliases, the pd doesn't show!

However, If I type bash (I'm using the fish shell) the terminal goes back to normal (sorry for my high-tech lingo) and the aliases are created and I can use them!

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I see you’ve found a way to sort it. However, I suspect your original method (in the question) will work - but only if you tell the shell to re-read your .bashrc file: once you’ve saved your edited file, type . .bashrc (note the leading . followed by space) - and it should work. Alternatively close and reopen the terminal.

Comment: @Will I didn't type that, but I closed and reopened the terminal. I even restarted the computer xD Thanks anyway!

Comment: Might be interesting to see if forcing a .bashrc read as above would work - create a temporary alias in .bashrc and try forcing the read then see if it works - just for interest / next time you need to do this. I don’t use fish so may not be good advice I gave!

Comment: @Will I wrote it as you said (just typed . .bashrc on the terminal) and got back this:

.bashrc (line 6): 'case' builtin not inside of switch block
case $- in
^
from sourcing file .bashrc
.: Error while reading file “.bashrc”

I don't know what this means.

Comment: Fish and bash are both shells, they are the same kind of thing, but they are not the same shell. `.bashrc` is the configuration file for the bash shell, anything you do there won't affect the fish shell. If you want to do things to fish, you need to modify _its_ configuration file, not bash's! This is why nothing works for you until you run `bash`: running `bash` starts a new bash shell, and since you have modified bash's configuration file, the changes will take effect now that you run bash.

Comment: @terdon it makes sense! Is there a way to do these modifications generally, I mean, for any shell?

Comment: @RichHardFineMan no. They are completely independent things. Basically, it's like filling up the tires on one car and expecting that to affect the tires of another car. Yes, they are both cars, but work done on one doesn't affect the other. The same goes for shells: each is a completely independent program. Now, some shells do share certain files like `~/.profile`, but fish isn't one of them and you cannot generalize, it will always depend on the specific shells you are using. For one thing, as is the case with bash and fish, the format of the conf files can be completely different.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in the fish shell, you type

```
alias pd="pwd"
```

which creates a temporary alias. To turn it into a permanent one you do

```
funcsave pd
```